# node-webkit with c++ addon to command printer

Tags: javascript, c++, dll, node-webkit

Recently, I have been use node-webkit to develop a client side project. And it have to command a special printer through the 'dll'.

So I need to add a C++ addon to load dll.(TSCLIB.dll is in the same dir with the C++ code)
Compile with the nw-gyp. 
Here is the C++ addon code:

```
#include <node.h>
#include <v8.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <exception>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
using namespace v8;

Handle<Value> OpenPort(const Arguments& args) {
  HandleScope scope;
  HINSTANCE hDLL;
  hDLL = LoadLibrary("TSCLIB.dll");
  if(hDLL){
    return scope.Close(String::New("hDLL is not null."));
  }else{
    return scope.Close(String::New("hDll is null."));
  }
}

void init(Handle<Object> exports) {
  exports->Set(String::NewSymbol("openport"),FunctionTemplate::New(OpenPort)->GetFunction());
}
NODE_MODULE(tscPrinter, init);
```

When I use the javascript to reqeuire this module.
And call the function openport("USB");
the result is "hDll is null".

Can somebody help me,please?? Thx a lot...